# how to convert complex graphing math into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I have this Desmos graph: [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vqmidlg14v)

I was wondering if there was someone who could maybe provide some guidance for translating this into JavaScript. I understand most of the math, I just lack the knowledge on how to represent it in JS. My main goal is to calculate the position of rotating points on a JS canvas. I have already translated the canvas so that the coordinate system mirrors one of a mathematical graph.

```
ctx.translate(c.width/2, c.height/2);
ctx.scale(1, -1)
```

I would like to have 3 variables. The x and y of the player's current pos, the point of rotation x and y, and the target x and y.

Please let me know if I can provide more detail or any other info that could be of use.

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use JS Math object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: I know about Math. method, I just don't know how to specifically represent certain parts of my graph such as: R(P,C,d) as a variable

Comment: I did not downvote the question but my guess is that the question is a little bit broad and asks for general directions instead of a specific point. I.e. it is on the brink of `how can I do this operation which requires pages of code` instead of `I wrote this function but it gives me 9 instead of 6`.

Comment: @JSman225, your question is a bit ambiguous, do you want to know how to write the math using js or how to visualize it?

Comment: How to write the math using JS. Some of the math concepts in the Desmos I haven't seen in JS before

Comment: It would be better to simply ask which how to translate certain specific Desmos math concepts into JS.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will keep that advice in mind.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with builtin api from canvas, example as below.

```
// x coordinate
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(150, 0);
ctx.stroke();

// y coordinate
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(0, 150);
ctx.stroke();

// point
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(75, 75, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
ctx.fill();
```

see details in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes

for complex graph, you can use d3.js library, see https://d3js.org/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I was masking for advice more along like lines of, how to translate some of the complex math equations into JS. I am well versed in the Canvas API, but I appreciate your willingness to contribute.

Comment: then you can look at the javascript math api in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: This didnt really answer my question, but you gave your advice, and your advice was correct in teaching how to use JS canvas. I will gift you the rep bounty

Comment: @JSman225 lucky me :)